# Qual o linux mais completo para programadores?

Tags: linux

Eu estudo programação por hobby há uns 4 anos, comecei com [php](/questions/tagged/php), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), aprendi um pouco de tudo, mas agora estou pensando em ir mais a fundo. Sempre usei o Windows que aliás sempre gostei muito, mas sinto que o Linux pode me oferecer uma liberdade maior em certas tarefas, sem contar na sua estabilidade e performance.

Gostaria de saber de quem use e trabalhe com programação, qual poderia me indicar. Não ligo muito pra design então não precisa ser tão amigável assim a interface, eu estive olhando o [fedora](/questions/tagged/fedora) e me agradou muito mas como não sei se é uma boa escolha gostaria da opinião de vocês!

Grato desde já!

Comment: Gostaria de ressaltar que pesquisei também a respeito de cada um dos sistemas aqui comentados e decidi escolher por base do que pesquisei e não por opiniões aqui dadas a mim.
Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Eu testei Ubuntu, fedora e Mint realmente achei o Mint perfeito ao que eu procurava. Obrigado pela excelente resposta Cigano Morrison Mendez sanou todas as minhas dúvidas! Grato a todos também que responderam a minha pergunta!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Esta pergunta é bastante ampla, portanto irei pincelar as distribuições mais usadas e suas características.

## [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com)

É a distribuição que mais ganhou adeptos nos últimos dois anos. É um híbrido que funciona misturando repositórios Ubuntu e Debian (ver mais abaixo). Está em primeiro lugar nas distribuições, segundo o [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com).

Possui uma filosofia que mistura código livre e proprietário, sendo o código proprietário formado basicamente por codecs de vídeo e drivers de mídia.

Sendo bastante eclético e suportando largamente o `apt-get`, é a distribuição que eu recomendaria para começar.

## [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com)

É o Linux com o maior apelo comercial e de Marketing, estando em 2o lugar pelo ranking da [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com). É desenvolvido pela [Canonical](http://www.canonical.com) e foi uma das distribuições que mais se desenvolveram nos últimos tempos. Começou como um *fork* do Debian, mas desenvolveu características peculiares rapidamente.

Diferentemente do Debian e assim como o Linux Mint, possui uma filosofia mais tolerante em relação a drivers e código proprietário (o Debian é 100% livre, o que faz com que determinados drivers também o sejam, sendo inferiores aos proprietários). O sistema de empacotamento primário é o `apt-get` e é um dos únicos que possui uma *App Store*, que mistura software livre e pago.

Possui aqui na rede Stack Exchange um site inteiramente dedicada a ela: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

## [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org)

É a alternativa livre patrocinada pela [Red Hat](http://redhat.com). Está em 5o lugar no ranking de distribuições, segundo o [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com). A ideia é copiar algumas das funcionalidades do Red Hat, mas sem focar no usuário empresarial, e sim no usuário doméstico.

O sistema de empacotamento primário é o `yum`.

## [Debian](http://debian.org)

é uma das distribuições Linux mais antigas, possuindo uma das maiores comunidades. Está em 3o lugar pelo ranking da [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com). Possui 100% do código livre.

O sistema de empacotamento primário é o `apt-get`

---

## Instalando uma distribuição

Antes de sair formatando disco, recomendo que você instale uma distribuição Linux dentro de uma máquina virtual para não comprometer o estado atual do seu computador. Há vários softwares de máquina virtual gratuitos, mas o que eu recomendo é o [VirtualBox da Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: Vale ressaltar que a parceria [se] / Ubuntu é tal que ambos sites compartem o menu superior, e não sei de nenhum outro site SE que tenha isso. Eu escolhi Ubuntu basicamente por isso: tem um site aqui e quase todas as dúvidas iniciais tem uma Q&A com a solução imediata.

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente vai querer usar a distribuição que tem a maior base de usuários. Maior comunidade = maior chance de vc achar soluções pros seus problemas no google.
Vai de ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Vai de Linux Mint, rápido, leve e fácil de achar soluções.

Answer (score 1):

Particularmente prefiro o Ubuntu. Uso desde que iniciei no curso de Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas.